# Elastic Search sorting with script with Pinned documents at positions

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, pinning

Ours is an eCommerce site and we pin certain pseudo Skus at definitive positions like 3, 12, 18 etc
We're planning to bring user personalisation with behaviors and play it in to search
I'm planning to use Sorting with Script, but also wanted to retain pseudo sku's positions (3,12,18)
and exclude from sorting script
Is there a way to do it in Elastic Search

Comment: Sample docs & mapping please. Also, what script have you come up with so far?

Comment: Currently the pinning feature in Elasticsearch only allows for pinning results to the top op the SRP. (And doesn't;t work with sorting) You could look at rescoring api and see what you can do logic wise there, but don't expect a lot from ES in this area! Let me know if you need some examples

Comment: Thanks @ByronVoorbach. I have one question, for rescoring, can rescoring be done from page2 only. Use case is we are trying to learn user interests in page 1 and want to rescore basing on behavior from page 2 with out impacting page 1 sort results